Is there a fast way to get all visible objects in camera's FOV that occupy over a certain size
I would like to get a list of all of the objects visible to the camera that occupy over a certain area (let's say a 900px area for a 1920x1080 resolution camera)
Currently I have the following code which gives out a list of objects visible to the camera but this doesn't let me filter by size.
    def is_object_visible(self, obj):
        scene = bpy.context.scene
        camera = self.camera
        # Check if object is not hidden
        if not obj.visible_get():
            return False
        # If object has no geometry, skip
        if obj.type != "MESH":
            return False
        # Check if any of the object's bounding box corners are within the camera's view frustum
        obj_bound_box = [
            obj.matrix_world @ mathutils.Vector(corner) for corner in obj.bound_box
        ]
        for corner in obj_bound_box:
            co_ndc = world_to_camera_view(scene, camera, corner)
            if 0.0 <= co_ndc.x <= 1.0 and 0.0 <= co_ndc.y <= 1.0 and co_ndc.z >= 0.0:
                return True
        return False

Some of the approaches I've seen online, like doing an id pass 10x my render time. Any suggestions would be appreciated
Thanks
